# Solr spatial search not returning any results in response element

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using Solr version 6.2.1 and trying to return closest location for a given latitude and longitude.

I have manage to add data into Solr and indexed it.

My data file (.CSV) is in this format:

```
id,areaname,geo,country,state
1125257,"Mumbai","18.9750,72.8258","India","Maharashtra"
1125258,"Mumgaon","26.3833,93.4833","India","Assam"
1125259,"Mummasar","28.2167,74.2833","India","Rajasthan"
1125260,"Mummidivaram","16.6500,82.1167","India","Andhra Pradesh"
1125261,"Munaba","25.7500,70.2833","India","Rajasthan"
1125262,"Munabao","25.7500,70.2833","India","Rajasthan"
1125263,"Munabo","25.7500,70.2833","India","Rajasthan"
1125264,"Munagala","17.0500,79.8333","India","Andhra Pradesh"
```

Under managed-schema file following fields are setup:

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
```

and field geo as:

```
<field name="geo" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="geo_0_coordinate" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="geo_1_coordinate" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

Now when I am running my query to find closest location, it is returning nothing in response element.

```
{!geofilt sfield=geo}&pt=28.2167,74.2833&d=100
```

No error in logs and data is indexed.

Please could someone explain me as to why this is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solr Replace solr.LatLonType TO solr.LatLonPointSpatialField
I just used LatLonPointSpatialField to fix this problem.
Tow field _coordinate are no need.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10238               Remove LatLonType in 7.0; replaced by LatLonPointSpatialField